# Can I use Moq's SetupSequence to throw exception then return void?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I am trying to set up Moq to throw an exception on the first invocation and then return void on the second invocation. The method I'm mocking has a `void` return type (e.g. `public void Bar()`).

**Things I have tried**

This has compile errors because `Returns` requires an argument and `SetupSequence` requires type arguments.

```
_mock.SetupSequence(m => m.Bar())
    .Throws<Exception>()
    .Returns();
```

This has a compile error because `Void` is not a type in C#.

```
_mock.SetupSequence<IMyMock, Void>(m => m.Bar())
    .Throws<Exception>() // first invocation throws exception
    .CallBase();
```

**Workaround**

In the end I gave up on `SetupSequence()` and switched to `Callback()` to throw an exception.

```
var firstTime = true;
_mock.Setup(m => m.Bar())
    .Callback(() =>
    {
        if (firstTime)
        {
            firstTime = false;
            throw new Exception();
        }
    });
```

**Question**

`SetupSequence` takes a `Func`, not an `Action`. Am I correct in assuming that this means `SetupSequence()` cannot be used to mock void methods?

Comment: As far as I know, `Setup` defines the same behaviour for every invocation. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this starting with Moq 4.8.0:

`SetupSequence` support for `void` methods was discussed in GitHub issue [`#451`](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/451) and added with GitHub pull request [`#463`](https://github.com/moq/moq4/pull/463).

You're probably looking for the new **`.Pass()`** method:

```
mock.SetupSequence(m => m.VoidMethod())
    .Throws(new InvalidOperationException())
    .Pass()
    .Pass()
    .Throws(new InvalidOperationException())
    .Pass();
```

Note that trailing calls to `.Pass()` are probably unnecessary.

Comment: `Note that trailing calls to .Pass() are probably unnecessary.`  So does this mean that these 2 are equivalent:

Comment: mock.SetupSequence(m => m.VoidMethod())
    .Throws(new InvalidOperationException())
    .Pass()

Comment: mock.SetupSequence(m => m.VoidMethod())
    .Throws(new InvalidOperationException())